# WebRTC for Android - how to play AudioTrack object in OnAddStream callback?

Tags: java, android, node.js, webrtc

I am trying to build an Android client that receives streaming audio only from another device. I have a nodeJS server which establishes a socket IO connection to my android client. The following is a subset of my webRTC code for the socket.io on message

```
            ... if (type.equals("candidate")) {
                    Log.d(TAG,"AddIceCandidateCommand");
                    PeerConnection pc = peers.get(from).pc;
                    if (pc.getRemoteDescription() != null) {
                        IceCandidate candidate = new IceCandidate(
                                from,
                                data.getInt("label"),
                                data.getString("candidate")
                        );
                        pc.addIceCandidate(candidate);
                    }
                } else if (type.equals("offer")) {
                    // offer == we got an offer, create an answer to the offer
                    Log.d(TAG,"Offer message");
                    ReceiveObserver receiveObserver = new ReceiveObserver();
                    Peer peer = addPeer(from);

                    SessionDescription sdp = new SessionDescription(
                            SessionDescription.Type.fromCanonicalForm(data.getString("type")),
                            data.getString("sdp")
                    );
                    peer.pc.setRemoteDescription(receiveObserver, sdp);
                    peer.pc.createAnswer(receiveObserver, sdpConstraints);
                }
```

After connecting offer answer handshake process, I receive an onAddStream callback in my android client with a MediaStream object:

```
@Override
    public void onAddStream(MediaStream mediaStream) {
        Log.d(TAG,"onAddStream "+mediaStream.label());
        AudioTrack track = mediaStream.audioTracks.get(0);
        track.setEnabled(true);
    }
```

but this MediaStream object only has one AudioTrack and zero VideoTracks. How do I stream this one audio track on the device? From the documentation it looks like only VideoTrack objects can be rendered, am I looking at the wrong callback?

Comment: Did you find any solution to this in the meantime?

Comment: Any solution? have the same problem here..

Answer (score -1):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33888622/3117296) is my Full working code on SO in which stream is getting played fine.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not solve the problem since your code as well checks for videoTracks.size() == 1